# Alamofire doesn't make GET Request but call completion handler with Success

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, iphone-x

As an object, I have a problem with Alamofire (the same happens with AFNetworking) with an App Distributed internally which I can't debug the real Device; in particular with the iPhone X iOS 12.1.3 and only one device have this problem.

The requests work fine for all Testers, but in one iPhone X, without apparent reason, the Alamofire/AFNetwork, GET/POST, requests stop to come to the Web Service (I have access to real time log of WS and there are no request), but it seems that completion block with Success was called and the App follow the correct flow.

I can't debug this device and I don't know what happens; The Tester does not do any particular action to get this error.

This is one request of the many that do not work; I repeat, all work fine for an hour, after I don't know what happens, kill and reopen the App doesn't work.

```
    Alamofire.request(completePath, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: ServiceSupport.sharedInstance.headerAlamofire()).responseJSON { (responseObject) in

        if let json = responseObject.result.value {
            if(ServiceSupport().headerIsOk(dictResponse: json as! NSDictionary)) {
                completion(SUCCESS, "")
            } else {
                completion(FAIL, "ERROR")
            }
        } else {
            completion(FAIL, "ERROR")
        }

    }
}
```

Someone can help me? Has anyone happened?
Thanks to all.

Edit:
The server should return different data when the request stop coming to WebService; Moreover I have the same problem, with the same Device, with AFNetworking.

Edit 2:
Response Header
[Response]:  { URL: http://******/configuration } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "Keep-Alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        1060
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Thu, 31 Jan 2019 13:03:23 GMT"
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5, max=100"
    );
    Server =     (
        Apache
    );
    "Set-Cookie" =     (
        "JSESSIONID=96A0D1E4419A353E6115E34451793951; Path=/; HttpOnly"
    );
    "X-Frame-Options" =     (
        SAMEORIGIN
    );
    "X-XSS-Protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} }

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: After 1 hours, what happens? Do you get request to the Web service? Did you try setting local cache as `nil` for `URLSessionConfirguration` and request cache policy as `.reloadIgnoringCacheData`?

Comment: After an hour requests stop to come to the Web Service but it seems that completion block with Success was called because the App follow the correct flow. Now I try to set the local cache; It's difficult to test because its is a random problem. How can the Cache can be a problem and why only in one Device?

Comment: Yes, try it because it happens to be an issue where the local cache is used for the requests so no Web Service call. But did you notice the data it returns is same for that period of time when it's behaving like this? It should be same as there is no data fetching from the actual service. And if it's same data then i think caching is the issue.

Comment: I try, but the server should return different data and I have the same problem, with the same device with AFNetworking.

Comment: What are the response headers of  your WebService?

Comment: @weso sorry had a few questions opened and posted on wrong one

Comment: Yes, I would take a look at the headers and the data being returned in the completion block.  If these are consistently the same when no request is going to your server then possibly you are seeing a caching response.

Comment: @Gereon I have edited my question with the response header.

Comment: So it's not an obvious caching problem. Nevertheless, I would suggest you try @Kamram's suggestion of using `.reloadIgnoringCacheData`, and you could also try to explicity forbid caching by adding a response header like `Cache-Control: no-store` or `Cache-Control: max-age=0`

Comment: Now I make a new build with explicit cache disabled. I keep you updated!

Comment: Thanks all! The cache was the problem: URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all, the problem was the Cache!

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
```

This work for me.